# Structure Offset Error

Tags: assembly, kernel, intel

I am trying to boot a custom kernel in QEMU. It is crashing horribly just after interrupts are enabled, due to an error in calculating the address to jump to to handle the interrupt.

I have a bit of assembly code that retrieves values from offsets [in a C structure](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/mach/i386/thread_status.h#L346-L357). Specifically, I am trying to get the fields `trapno`, `trapfn`, and `err`. Note that I `push` the values of those three fields onto the end of the stack before I try to retrieve them. [Here is the code that does the `push`ing](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L108-L131).

However, when the code is run, I get the values of the `rip`, `cs`, and `rflags` fields, respectively. The crash is due to the fact that `cs` is not a valid `trapfn` function address. Here is an overview of the order of execution, as it is in reality a bit more complicated than the above explanation implies:

1. The IDT entry function `push`es the error number, or a dummy number that takes its place (because not all interrupts have an error number), onto the stack. ([Source](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L122))
2. The address of the interrupt handler (the value of `trapfn`) is `push`ed onto the stack. ([Source](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L109))
3. The interrupt number is `push`ed onto the stack. ([Source](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L110))
4. A buffer is allocated on the stack to save the values of the general-purpose registers. This structure has a size equal to the size of [struct x86_saved_state](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/mach/i386/thread_status.h#L367-L406) minus the size of [struct x86_64_intr_stack_frame](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/mach/i386/thread_status.h#L346-L356).
5. All the general-purpose registers are saved to their fields in `struct x86_saved_state`, located by their offsets. As far as I can tell, this step works just fine. ([Source](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L182-L203))
6. The `trapno` is extracted by its offset inside `struct x86_saved_state` and stored into ebx. **This step has a bug**; the value of the `rip` field is being returned instead.
7. The `trapfn` is extracted by its offset inside `struct x86_saved_state` and stored into edx. **This step also has a bug**; the value of the `cs` field is being returned instead.
8. The `cs` field is extracted by its offset inside `struct x86_saved_state` and stored into esi. **This step *may* have a bug**; I cannot tell at this point. ([Source](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L205-L207) for steps 6–8)

(Note: [Here](https://gist.github.com/wjk/eef6d4e2d2eacd6114f6) is the file that contains the offsets used.)

Does anyone here know why steps 6–8 would manifest the bug described above? Thank you very much for your efforts; this particular crash has been stumping me for months now!

Comment: Why do the offsets start from 16 (`R64_RDI`)?

Comment: @Jester: As it turns out, there was a bug in the file that generates the offset list: offsetof() is called on the wrong structure type. That wrong structure has 16 bytes of padding at the beginning, which is what you saw.